# Is that possible to quit a Window in Eclipse in OS X full screen mode in shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, macos

When using Eclipse in full screen mode in OS X, if I have two windows(use menu->Window->New Window) and I want to quit one of them. I have to move my mouse to the top-right corner of the screen to quit the full screen mode, then click the close button on the top-left corner to close the window.

I think that is too slow I want to use a shortcut to replace that. However, I find out the close and close all in Menu->File is for Editor only, not for Window. And Command + Q will close both Window and Quit Eclipse, which is not what I want.

So is there a trick to do this or I should just let it go?

Thank you.

Comment: I just filed this as a bug to Eclipse's bugzilla. [Bug 415193](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415193)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Command-W`, it should close the current window.

Comment: As far as I know, Alt+F4 is a shortcut in Microsoft Windows and my question is in OS X. However, I do test alt+f4 and it does not work.

Comment: @OwenZhao I noticed that too and updated. The equivalent shortcut is `command-w` according to apple's website.

Comment: Command+w is still no. In eclipse, Command+w are for close the editor tabs, which is as mentioned by my question 'I find out the close and close all in Menu->File is for Editor only, not for Window.' I also test to remove the shortcut in Eclipse and see if the System will take over command+w back. And still, nothing happened. Thanks any way.

Comment: @OwenZhao That is crazy that Eclipse overrides an OS command. Sorry I couldn't help more.